# Лямбда выражения в Java

Tags: java

Помогите решить задачу, целый день бьюсь - никак( если возможно, в пояснениями.
Заранее очень благодарен)

> Для примера построим следующую комбинацию. Дан предикат `condition` и две функции `ifTrue` и `ifFalse`. Напишите метод `ternaryOperator`, который из них построит новую функцию, возвращающую значение функции `ifTrue`, если предикат выполнен, и значение `ifFalse` иначе.
>
> Пример использования метода (можно было все свернуть в одну строчку, но для наглядности все элементы вынесены в отдельные переменные):
>
> ```
>    Predicate<Object> condition = Objects::isNull;
>     Function<Object, Integer> ifTrue = obj -> 0;
>     Function<CharSequence, Integer> ifFalse = CharSequence::length;
>     Function<String, Integer> safeStringLength = ternaryOperator(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse);
> ```
>
> Результирующая функция будет для нулевых ссылок на `String` возвращать `0`, а для ненулевых ссылок возвращать длину строки.
>
> В качестве дополнительного задания самостоятельно разберите, почему у метода `ternaryOperator` такая сложная сигнатура.

Дан следующий шаблон:

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> ternaryOperator(
        Predicate<? super T> condition,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifTrue,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifFalse) {

    return null; // your implementation here   
}
```

Comment: если возможно, сделайте это в виде анонимного класса, а не лямбда выражения, чтобы было понятнее...

Comment: Не надо анонимного класса, с лямбами понятнее. return (T arg)->condition.test(arg)?ifTrue.apply(arg):ifFalse.apply(arg);

Comment: могли бы, пожалуйста объяснить, что делает эта строчка?

я понял, что вызывается функция condition и в зависимости от её выпонения вызываются 2 другие, но подскажите, что конкретно происходит здесь? 
(T arg)->
ну или не могли бы написать, как это будет с точки зрения анонимного класса?

Comment: Возвращает требуемую по условию задачи лямбду. Лямбда же, будучи вызываной, вызывает condition и затем ifTrue либо ifFalse.

Comment: Те (T arg) и есть лямбда? просто я думал, что лямбда это выражение...  если честно я запутался

Comment: Да, лямбда это выражение. Причем простейшего типа - изображение. Как "1.0" - это изображение вещественной единицы.

Comment: Может, лучше хаскель взять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот вам анонимный класс:

```
 return  // your implementation here
         // as lambda: (T arg)->condition.test(arg)?ifTrue.apply(arg):ifFalse.apply(arg);
         // as anonymous class instance:
            new Function<T, U>() {
                @Override
                public U apply(T arg) {
                    return condition.test(arg)?ifTrue.apply(arg):ifFalse.apply(arg);
                }
            };
```

Comment: спасибо большое, по анонимному классу смог разобраться, буду учиться дальше

Comment: Благодарю, хороший пример и ответ!